# How to get only hour and seconds using localtime() in Python

Tags: python

How do I get hour and seconds separate using this..

```
localtime = time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time()))
print(localtime)
```

This results in this..

```
Thu Oct 11 17:23:28 2018
```

I just need to know how to get the hour and seconds separate, and if that's not possible with *localtime()* then how else could I do it?

I'm not that good at coding but am trying to work on a project and can't find any informative documentation on what I need.

Comment: `time.localtime` returns a data structure from which you can retrieve single data items like hour or second. Read the Python docs for detail. Or you use `time.strftime` instead of `time.asctime` (the docs tell you how you can define the output format of `strftime`)

Comment: [Here are the docs you couldn't find.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`time.strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime) function is what you're after:

> Convert a tuple or `struct_time` representing a time as returned by `gmtime()` or `localtime()` to a string as specified by the *format* argument.

To get the required output, use the following format string:

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M %Y", time.localtime())
'Thu Oct 11 17:23:28 2018'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in split function, which splits strings into array elements by checking for patterns. Default is ' ', e.g.

```
'abc def'.split()
```

will return

```
['abc', 'def']
```

So, applying this:

```
localtime = localtime.split()
```

will return:

```
['Thu','Oct','11','17:23:28','2018']
```

we want to extract the 4th element of the array, and arrays start at 0, so:

```
localtime = localtime[3]
```

this returns:

```
'17:23:28'
```

now, we need to split again, this time the ':' character:

```
localtime = localtime.split(':')
```

this returns:

```
['17','23','28']
```

now, for the last part:

extract the individual values:

```
hour = localtime[0]
minute = localtime[1]
second = localtime[2]
```

Comment: I never knew you could do that, again I am not that good at coding. Thank you, this might help with other projects I am working on but have put off just because of that problem.

Answer (score 0):

import time

secondVariable=time.localtime()[5]

hourVariable=time.localtime()[3]